# Find all of the values in a list that are repeated the most

Tags: python

I have a list of objects and I would like to see which ones are the most common. It is easy to find *the* or *a* most common object using python's `Counter`, but I haven't found a simple way to find *all* of the most common objects. The code below is working but I would guess there's a better way to do this.

```
from collections import Counter

input_lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 1]

counts = Counter(input_lst)
ranked_counts = counts.most_common().copy()
first_common_obj = ranked_counts.pop(0)
equally_common_objs = [first_common_obj[0]]
while ranked_counts:
    next_obj = ranked_counts.pop(0)
    if first_common_obj[1] == next_obj[1]:
        equally_common_objs.append(next_obj[0])
    else:
        break

print(equally_common_objs)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be easier, and have better performance, to iterate over `Counter.most_common()` rather than using `.pop(0)` lots.

From here you just want to use `next` until the value is not the same. Which is effectively what you're doing with `.pop`.

```py
from collections import Counter

input_lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 1]

counts = Counter(input_lst)
items = iter(counts.most_common())
value, amount = next(items)
values = [value]
while True:
    value, a = next(items)
    if amount != a:
        break
    values.append(value)

print(values)
```

This is effectively grouping consecutive values together, and so you can instead use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) rather than roll your own.

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

input_lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 1]

_, values = next(groupby(Counter(input_lst).most_common(), lambda i: i[1]))
values = [value for value, _ in values]
print(values)
```

Comment: The first solution hit a StopIteration and then crashed, but the second solution worked for me (Python 3.7.6).

Comment: @jss367 That issue is present in your original code.

Comment: @jss367 There is an additional issue that will cause a `StopIteration` error in both my solutions and an `IndexError` in yours. Please properly test your code, before blaming me for causing errors in your code.